# How do you restart a head node in Powershell HPC?

Tags: powershell, admin, hpc

I'm a Powershell noob at work and I've been given a task to reboot the Microsoft HPC grid nodes. I also need to be able to restart the head node of the group.

I know how to restart the compute nodes ie:

```
Restart-HpcNode -Name $computeNode -Scheduler $headnode -Comment "Testing"
```

However, you're not allowed to do this:

```
Restart-HpcNode -Name $headnode  -Scheduler $headnode -Comment "Testing"
```

WARNING: Node  will not be restarted because it is a head node.

Can you actually reboot the head node via Powershell with the HPC snapin?

Answer (score 0):

you can always use clusrun to restart all (or part) of your nodes

```
clusrun shutdown /r
```

If you Must use powershell and the Restart-HpcNode cmd isn't working for you i suggest you ignore the fact that it's an HPC head node and try using:

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $headnode
```